# React Native: GraphQL Mutation requests failing in OnePlus device

Tags: android, react-native, graphql, oneplus7

I'm facing issue in mutation with Apollo client. That too, brand/device specific issue with OnePlus devices. All the functions are working as expected in iOS and other android devices[like, Samsung, Oppo, Moto, Mi]. But, with OnePlus, i'm facing issue. Anybody having idea behind it.

I'm using React native, Apollo client with graphQl, for data requests.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Resolved this issue. The problem is date format of OnePlus devices.